# Why is that vias are generally made of tungsten while contact is made using aluminum?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, via, manufacturing, contact

From [this](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/in-vlsi-what-is-called-via-and-contact.246754/) thread:

```
Contact is connection to source, drain or poly.  While vias is used to
make connection between two metal layers.  Both vias and contact are
formed using metals.  Vias are generally made of tungsten while
contact is made using aluminum.
```

Why is that vias are generally made of tungsten while contact is made using aluminum? Is it because of conductivity, cost or something else?

**EDIT: this question is about vias and contacts in VLSI.**

Comment: This isn't universal. One process I use, which is commericalized by a major silicon foundry, uses Cu for all metallizations and vias, tungsten from poly/diff to M1, and aluminum on the uppermost pad layer only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.enigmatic-consulting.com/semiconductor_processing/CVD_Fundamentals/films/W_WSi.html) web page:

> Deposition of pure W can be used to fill the holes that make contact
> to the transistor source and drain ("contact holes") and also to fill
> vias between successive layers of metal. This approach is known as a
> tungsten plug process. Tungsten is used because of the extraordinarily
> good conformality of CVD from WF6. It is necessary to provide an
> adhesion/barrier layer such as Ti/TiN, to protect the underlying Si
> from attack by fluorine and to ensure adhesion of W to the silicon
> dioxide

W = Tungsten (from Wolfram)

CVD = Chemical Vapour Deposition

WF6 = Tungsten(VI) fluoride, also known as tungsten hexafluoride

Ti/TiN = Titanium/Titanium Nitride

Si = Silcon

As the web page explains in some detail, the tungsten plug-aluminum conductor interface is prone to electromigration failure due to the aluminum, while copper interconnects are more resilient.

Answer (score -6):

This is a novel case and not generally true.
Vias are made of copper and often filled with solder.

The problem is in the question from missing assumptions.

Semiconductor vias or [TSV's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through-silicon_via) [have  several choices.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_integrated_circuit)

Comment: What you're talking about is vias on a circuit board. I think the question is asking about vias on a semiconductor die.

Comment: @hearth Then you ought to down vote the question , is that logical/\?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I think Hearth was politely trying to say that the question is clearly about vias on a semiconductor die, given the link provided in the question. Hence your "answer" does not answer the question asked.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question or the answer. I was just saying that your answer is probably not interpreting the question correctly.

Comment: Note the Ratchet Effect

Comment: I do apologize for not mentioning it clear in the post.

Comment: Note to Moderators how voting does not reflect changes in answers..the Ratchet Effect is a flaw in this forum and how it is managed